# Issue when clicking enter button in CellEditorDialog using MultiLineTextCellEditor in nattable eclispe

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, nattable

When editing multiple cell content in nattable using *MultiLineTextCellEditor* the opened *CellEditorDialog* text area collapses when enter is clicked instead of OK button as in the below attached image.

Before Pressing Enter

[image]

After Pressing Enter

[image]

```java
MultiLineTextCellEditor textCellEditor = new MultiLineTextCellEditor(true) {

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean openInline(final IConfigRegistry configRegistry, final List<String> configLabels) {
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public boolean openMultiEditDialog() {
      return super.openMultiEditDialog();
    }
};

configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, textCellEditor, DisplayMode.NORMAL,
    COMMENT_CNG_LBL + "_" + COMMENT_COL_NUMBER);
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITABLE_RULE, IEditableRule.ALWAYS_EDITABLE,
    DisplayMode.EDIT, COMMENT_CNG_LBL + "_" + COMMENT_COL_NUMBER);
```

But the similar issue doesn't occur when using a *TextCellEditor* in nattable.

I need Multi Line inline cell editing feature so i cannot go for *TextCellEditor*

Please let me know if there some specific configuration that i am missed.

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that for single cell you want to edit multiline text inline?

Because it looks like a bug. When the multi-value dialog is opened for a multiline value, the dialog should show a multiline input field. But in your case it only shows a single line input field. So I assume the configurations collide here.

Feel free to open a ticket via Bugzilla.